# I have forgotten my Ubuntu One password

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have forgotten my Ubuntu One password.

How can I reset my Ubuntu One password, without knowing the original password?

Or do I need to start a new account?

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/i-forgot-my-password-how-can-i-get-into-my-account/).

The site walks you through the process.